# Disable gradle "wearApp" configuration

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

Running `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` shows that a active **`wearApp`** configuration exists:

```
Creating configuration compile
Creating configuration publish
Creating configuration provided
Creating configuration wearApp
Creating configuration androidTestCompile
Creating configuration androidTestPublish
Creating configuration androidTestProvided
Creating configuration androidTestWearApp
Creating configuration testCompile
Creating configuration testPublish
Creating configuration testProvided
Creating configuration testWearApp
Creating configuration debugCompile
Creating configuration debugPublish
Creating configuration debugProvided
Creating configuration debugWearApp
Creating configuration testDebugCompile
Creating configuration testDebugPublish
Creating configuration testDebugProvided
Creating configuration testDebugWearApp
Creating configuration releaseCompile
Creating configuration releasePublish
Creating configuration releaseProvided
Creating configuration releaseWearApp
Creating configuration testReleaseCompile
Creating configuration testReleasePublish
Creating configuration testReleaseProvided
Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp
```

However, this particular project will never have a wearApp, hence the configuration does not need to be created.

How can I tell gradle to disable the **`wearApp`** configuration altogether?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @amadib not yet - but also I never asked on the tools mailing list.